# "Scroll Depth" Trigger not working properly on Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, triggers, google-tag-manager

I have been trying to use Scroll depth with Timer to initiate an event on Google Tag Manager. The issue that I am currently facing is, scroll depth trigger is only fired once. So, I wish to track this event for all my blog posts and have set it up accordingly.

Now, if I go to any page on my website, but do not scroll down, and then go to any blog post and scroll, the tag and trigger work perfectly fine.
However, if on any other page, other than the blog post, I scroll down and the scroll depth is fired, and then I go to any blog post, and scroll on that, it does not fire.

I have been looking for solutions all around, but can't find any. You can refer to the screenshots below for reference. [scroll depth trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFUxg.png) [timer trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tk9eF.png) [trigger group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwLWr.png) [tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DgEt.png)

Answer (score 0):

What is likely happening is that when users navigate to other "posts" GTM isn't loading again thus the timer is not reset. This is because your blog is a SPA. In which case you should look at using history triggers to observe the change.

Comment: Hey, I am actually facing another similar issue! I would be glad if you could help. I have set up a group trigger (scroll depth + timer) for my blog. Now, if I directly go to the link of a blog post, the trigger works perfectly fine in Debug as well as when live. However, if I go to my landing page first, and then move to the blog post, it does not work. What is the issue here? Is it related to history trigger as well? You can refer the above screenshots for reference.

Comment: Yea, so your blog actually just does a fetch for some resource and injects the new data in, like a SPA. So GTM doesn't actually "load" again when you navigate. So your triggers will need to be based on history change.

Comment: Okay, got it. Could you point me to some resources that can help me out and solve this problem?